# How to run a simple angularjs application without webserver

Tags: angularjs, web-applications, webserver, project

I have three files - index.html, app.js and login.html in my application. Now my doubt is how to run my project like http://localhost/index.html. When i tried to click on index.html file, it simply opens a blank page. Please help me out.

Comment: using any scaffolding tools ??

Comment: What _should_ appear? Perhaps you should post some code.

Answer (score 0):

Couple of simple ways would be to use the built in webservers that come with php and python. Open a shell window `cd` to the directory where your files are the use either:

```
python -m SimpleHTTPServer
```

or

```
php -S localhost:8000
```

Then you can go to http://localhost:8000 in your browser, that said if you're seeing a blank screen you may have errors so maybe check the developer console.

Answer (score 0):

copy this and paste it into a file and name it package.json and put this in the root of your project. Then navigate to the project root using the command line tool and type npm install 1st let the packages get installed and then npm start.

then go to localhost:8000 
p.s. Need to install node 1st

```
{
  "name": "npm server",

  "dependencies": {
   //your dependencies here
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "http-server": "0.9.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "prestart": "npm update",
    "start": "http-server -a localhost -p 8000"
  }
}
```